# what is wrong with my vimrc configuration?

Tags: vim

I have installed the plugin--[pydiction](https://github.com/rkulla/pydiction),if i edit a new file which has no name,i can not use the auto-complete function,but i can use the auto-complete function in a named file,what is wrong with my _vimrc configuration?
Here is all my  lines in the _vimrc file.

```
set nocompatible
behave mswin
set langmenu=en_US
let $LANG = 'en_US'
set diffexpr=MyDiff()
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
function MyDiff()
  let opt = '-a --binary '
  if &diffopt =~ 'icase' | let opt = opt . '-i ' | endif
  if &diffopt =~ 'iwhite' | let opt = opt . '-b ' | endif
  let arg1 = v:fname_in
  if arg1 =~ ' ' | let arg1 = '"' . arg1 . '"' | endif
  let arg2 = v:fname_new
  if arg2 =~ ' ' | let arg2 = '"' . arg2 . '"' | endif
  let arg3 = v:fname_out
  if arg3 =~ ' ' | let arg3 = '"' . arg3 . '"' | endif
  let eq = ''
  if $VIMRUNTIME =~ ' '
    if &sh =~ '\<cmd'
      let cmd = '""' . $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff"'
      let eq = '"'
    else
      let cmd = substitute($VIMRUNTIME, ' ', '" ', '') . '\diff"'
    endif
  else
    let cmd = $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff'
  endif
  silent execute '!' . cmd . ' ' . opt . arg1 . ' ' . arg2 . ' > ' . arg3 . eq
endfunction
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
map <F4> :w<cr>:!python %<cr>
imap <F5> <Esc>:w <cr>:!python %<cr>
set number
filetype plugin on
let g:pydiction_location = 'D:/Vim/vimfiles/ftplugin/pydiction/complete-dict'
let g:pydiction_menu_height = 20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A link to that plugin would probably be useful but I'd say that this plugin does its job only in buffers with `filetype` set to `python`.

If you want it to work on unnamed buffers, use the following command:

```
:set filetype=python
```

Comment: i have google it ,and solved it as : `set directory=.,$TEMP`
 ,is the comma the meaning of logical `or` ,what is the meaning of `.,$TEMP` ?  http://cfc.kizzx2.com/index.php/gvim-e303-unable-to-open-swap-file-for-no-name-recovery-impossible/

Comment: The `directory` option tells Vim where to store and look for swap files. The `.` means "the directory of the current file", the coma is a separator and `$TEMP` is an environment variable supposedly expanded to the path of some directory on your system. I fail to see how it would be related to your problem.

Comment: From the [pydiction documentation](https://github.com/rkulla/pydiction): `Pydiction only uses the "Tab" key to complete, uses a special dictionary file to complete from, and only attempts to complete while editing Python files.` This means that, as romaini says, you need to `:set filetype=python` for this plugin to work in unnamed buffers.